# Typing of a decorator changing the return type causes problems with pyright upon usage

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing, typechecking

I have a decorator (called `returns`) that takes a function (besides the one it decorates) and applies it to the return value of the one it decorates e.g.:

```
@returns(list)
def generator():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
x = generator()
# x is [1,2,3], not a generator
```

The decorator is implemented and typed in the following way:

```
from __future__ import annotations

from functools import wraps as _wraps
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, Generic
from typing_extensions import ParamSpec

MethodParamSpec = ParamSpec('MethodParamSpec')

OuterInputType = TypeVar('OuterInputType')
OuterReturnType = TypeVar('OuterReturnType')


class returns(Generic[OuterInputType, OuterReturnType]):

    def __init__(self, type_: Callable[[OuterInputType], OuterReturnType]):
        self.__type = type_

    def __call__(
        self,
        func: Callable[MethodParamSpec, OuterInputType],
    ) -> Callable[MethodParamSpec, OuterReturnType]:

        @_wraps(func)
        def __new_func(*args: MethodParamSpec.args, **kwargs: MethodParamSpec.kwargs) -> OuterReturnType:
            val = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return self.__type(val)

        return __new_func
```

pyright has no problems with it, but it does with the following usages:

```
from _typeshed import ConvertibleToInt
from typing import TypeVar, Iterable, Union

from grok_returns_decorator import returns, __version__

T = TypeVar('T')
ConvertibleToIntType = TypeVar('ConvertibleToIntType', bound=ConvertibleToInt)
ConvertibleToIntOrNone = TypeVar('ConvertibleToIntOrNone', ConvertibleToInt, None)

@returns(tuple)
def tuple_range(n: int) -> Iterable[int]:
    yield from range(n)

assert tuple_range(5) == (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)

@returns(list)
def tuple_range(n: int) -> Iterable[int]:
    yield from range(n)

assert tuple_range(5) == [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

@returns(lambda x: 3 if x is None else int(x))
def parse_int(x: ConvertibleToIntOrNone) -> ConvertibleToIntOrNone:
    return x

assert parse_int(1) == 1
assert parse_int(1.5) == 1
assert parse_int('1') == 1
assert parse_int(None) == 3
```

The errors are the following (in order):

```
error: Argument of type "(n: int) -> Iterable[int]" cannot be assigned to parameter "func" of type "(**MethodParamSpec@__call__) -> Iterable[_T_co@tuple]" in function "__call__"
    Type "(n: int) -> Iterable[int]" cannot be assigned to type "(**MethodParamSpec@__call__) -> Iterable[_T_co@tuple]"
      Function return type "Iterable[int]" is incompatible with type "Iterable[_T_co@tuple]"
        "Iterable[int]" is incompatible with "Iterable[_T_co@tuple]"
          Type parameter "_T_co@Iterable" is covariant, but "int" is not a subtype of "_T_co@tuple"
            Type "int" cannot be assigned to type "_T_co@tuple" (reportArgumentType)
```

```
 error: Argument of type "(n: int) -> Iterable[int]" cannot be assigned to parameter "func" of type "(**MethodParamSpec@__call__) -> Iterable[_T@list]" in function "__call__"
    Type "(n: int) -> Iterable[int]" cannot be assigned to type "(**MethodParamSpec@__call__) -> Iterable[_T@list]"
      Function return type "Iterable[int]" is incompatible with type "Iterable[_T@list]"
        "Iterable[int]" is incompatible with "Iterable[_T@list]"
          Type parameter "_T_co@Iterable" is covariant, but "int" is not a subtype of "_T@list"
            Type "int" cannot be assigned to type "_T@list" (reportArgumentType)
```

```
error: Argument of type "OuterInputType@returns" cannot be assigned to parameter "__x" of type "ConvertibleToInt" in function "__new__"
    Type "OuterInputType@returns" cannot be assigned to type "ConvertibleToInt"
      "object*" is incompatible with "str"
      "object*" is incompatible with protocol "ReadableBuffer"
        "__buffer__" is not present
      "object*" is incompatible with protocol "SupportsInt"
        "__int__" is not present
      "object*" is incompatible with protocol "SupportsIndex"
        "__index__" is not present
```

What is the source of the problems?

Comment: Just typing in that there is certainly no problem during "usage" of this code, at runtime - the problems you are finding are at the "static type checking",  which is an optional step.  Other than that, yes, unfortunately typing Python code correctly is much harder than writing it.